# When I launch a project, I get an exception, this exception is factory already defined

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to build a spring project the way I did on the spring website, but now I've got an exception, the exception is factory already defined.

I downloaded the spring source code from github, and it has now compiled successfully in my local environment.I added a module called spring-demon. It has three Java files and a gradle configuration file.

Here are three Java files

```
public class MyWebApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletCxt) {

        // Load Spring web application configuration
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ac = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ac.register(AppConfig.class);
        ac.refresh();

        // Create and register the DispatcherServlet
        DispatcherServlet servlet = new DispatcherServlet(ac);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration = servletCxt.addServlet("app", servlet);
        registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        registration.addMapping("/app/*");
    }
}
```

```
@Controller
public class UsrController {

    @RequestMapping("/getUser.do")
    public Object getUser(){
        System.out.println("getUser");
        return null;
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com")
public class AppConfig {


}
```

Here is the configuration file for gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:2.2.3"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}
apply plugin: "com.bmuschko.tomcat"

group 'org.springframework'
version '5.0.14.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    provided group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.1.0'
    def tomcatVersion = '8.0.27'
    tomcat    "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:${tomcatVersion}",
            "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:${tomcatVersion}",
            "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:${tomcatVersion}"
    compile project(':spring-webmvc')
}
tomcat {
    httpPort = 8090
    stopPort = 8091
    //httpsPort = 8091
    enableSSL = true
}
```

Here is the exception stack information

```
> Task :buildSrc:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :buildSrc:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:assemble UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :buildSrc:compileTestGroovy NO-SOURCE
> Task :buildSrc:processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :buildSrc:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:test NO-SOURCE
> Task :buildSrc:check UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:build UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-core:cglibRepackJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-core:objenesisRepackJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-jcl:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-jcl:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-jcl:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :spring-jcl:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-jcl:inspectClassesForKotlinIC UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-jcl:jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-core:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-core:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-core:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :spring-core:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-core:inspectClassesForKotlinIC UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-core:jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-beans:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-beans:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :spring-beans:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-beans:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-beans:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-beans:inspectClassesForKotlinIC UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-beans:jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-aop:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-aop:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-aop:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-aop:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-aop:inspectClassesForKotlinIC UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-aop:jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-expression:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-expression:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-expression:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-expression:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-expression:inspectClassesForKotlinIC UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-expression:jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-instrument:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-instrument:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-instrument:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :spring-instrument:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-instrument:inspectClassesForKotlinIC UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-instrument:jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-context:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-context:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-context:compileGroovy NO-SOURCE
> Task :spring-context:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-context:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-context:inspectClassesForKotlinIC UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-context:jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-oxm:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-oxm:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-oxm:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-oxm:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-oxm:inspectClassesForKotlinIC UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-oxm:jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-web:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-web:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-web:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-web:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-web:inspectClassesForKotlinIC UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-web:jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-tx:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-tx:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-tx:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-tx:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-tx:inspectClassesForKotlinIC UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-tx:jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-jdbc:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-jdbc:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-jdbc:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-jdbc:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-jdbc:inspectClassesForKotlinIC UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-jdbc:jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-context-support:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-context-support:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-context-support:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-context-support:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-context-support:inspectClassesForKotlinIC UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-context-support:jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-webmvc:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-webmvc:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-webmvc:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-webmvc:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-webmvc:inspectClassesForKotlinIC UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-webmvc:jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-demo:compileKotlin
> Task :spring-demo:compileJava
> Task :spring-demo:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :spring-demo:classes

> Task :spring-demo:tomcatRun

Warning:
G:\spring\spring-framework\spring-framework\spring-demo\build\tmp\ssl\keystore -destkeystore G:\spring\spring-framework\spring-framework\spring-demo\build\tmp\ssl\keystore -deststoretype pkcs12" 迁移到行业标准格式 PKCS12。

A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/spring-demo]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/spring-demo]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@1b41223d]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.initInternal(StandardContext.java:6265)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.Error: factory already defined
    at java.net.URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(URL.java:1112)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.<init>(TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.getInstanceInternal(TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.register(TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.java:75)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.registerURLStreamHandlerFactory(StandardRoot.java:677)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.initInternal(StandardRoot.java:660)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 10 more

> Task :spring-demo:tomcatRun FAILED
A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:439)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:769)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:337)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat$start$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat$start$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.embedded.BaseTomcatServerImpl.start(BaseTomcatServerImpl.groovy:56)
    at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.embedded.TomcatServer$start$8.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.tasks.AbstractTomcatRun.startTomcat(AbstractTomcatRun.groovy:359)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:384)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:69)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:158)
    at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.tasks.AbstractTomcatRun$_validateConfigurationAndStartTomcat_closure2.doCall(AbstractTomcatRun.groovy:228)
    at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.tasks.AbstractTomcatRun$_validateConfigurationAndStartTomcat_closure2.doCall(AbstractTomcatRun.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
    at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.internal.LoggingHandler.withJdkFileLogger(LoggingHandler.groovy:56)
    at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.internal.LoggingHandler$withJdkFileLogger.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.tasks.AbstractTomcatRun.validateConfigurationAndStartTomcat(AbstractTomcatRun.groovy:227)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:384)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:69)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:158)
    at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.tasks.AbstractTomcatRun$_start_closure1.doCall(AbstractTomcatRun.groovy:220)
    at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.tasks.AbstractTomcatRun$_start_closure1.doCall(AbstractTomcatRun.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
    at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.internal.utils.TomcatThreadContextClassLoader.withClasspath(TomcatThreadContextClassLoader.groovy:30)
    at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.internal.utils.ThreadContextClassLoader$withClasspath.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.tasks.AbstractTomcatRun.start(AbstractTomcatRun.groovy:219)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:794)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:761)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBuildCacheKeyExecuter.execute(ResolveBuildCacheKeyExecuter.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:596)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:924)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':spring-demo:tomcatRun'.
> An error occurred starting the Tomcat server.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 8s
67 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 64 up-to-date
A child container failed during start
16:31:15: Task execution finished 'tomcatRun'.
```

I want the project to start properly, and I can access getuser.do through a browser, and see "getUser" on the console.

Comment: I guess my < usrcontroller.java > will cause this exception. I will try to delete < usrcontroller.java > and start the module again.The explanation should appear on the @controller annotation of UsrController. I don't know if my idea is correct.

Comment: Ref: https://github.com/dineshbhagat/spring-boot-web-jpa